# TextWrangler and BBEdit Multi-File Search not able to filter based on filename

Tags: textwrangler, bbedit

I wanted to use the Multi-File Search in TextWrangler and use Filter for filename. But When I try to enter Filter like Filename is file.txt, the OK button is disabled and is never enabled.

Documentation says TextWrangler is not compatible with macOS Sierra (10.13), but my OS is MacOS Sierra (10.12.6) and all other features of TextWrangler work fine. I understand that it is recommended to use BBEdit instead of TextWrangler but if I have to use TextWrangler then does anyone know why the OK button for filter is disabled. Also wondering if TextWrangler also has any free vs premium feature difference and if the multi-file search filter is not part of free version, since I am using the free version.

Comment: Downloaded and installed BBEdit and even that has the same issue. Sine the first 30 days has all features enabled in BBEdit so this does not seem to be feature-disabled-due-to-free-version issue.

Answer (score 0):

To enable the OK-button a name must be entered in the top text field of the filter dialog.